# Cannot Install Java Web Services Developer Pack 2.0 on Windows System

Tags: java, xjc

I am trying to install the Java Web Services Developer Pack 2.0 on a Windows system.  I downloaded `jwsdp-2_0-windows-i586` and ran it in a CMD window with Administrator privileges.  When run, it reports:

`A suitable JVM could not be found. Please run the program again using the option -is:javahome <JAVA HOME DIR>`

So then I tried providing the requested information:

`jwsdp-2_0-windows-i586 -is:javahome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102"`

And again it reports there's no suitable JVM, yet the JVM is installed:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?